# Using Sessions in dynamic texboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, textbox, session-variables

Alright so I need to save each input from the textbox's in a session variable.  The problem is that this is dynamic, meaning that the texbox ID is NatureTextbox_1, NatureTexbox_2 ect. And this makes it hard to save per session variable due to the infintite amount of texbox's available.  I have been pounding my head against the wall trying to figure this out and am resorting to being a noob and asking you guys for your advice.  If you can give me any information on what to do I'd appreciate it.

This is the C# Code (Remember the textbox's are dynamic meaning infinite):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add any controls that have been previously added dynamically

    for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumberAdded; ++i)
    {
        AddControls(i + 1);
    }

}
private void AddControls(int controlNumber)
{




    var newPanel = new Panel();
    var natureLabel = new Label();
    var dateLabel = new Label();
    var fatalLabel = new Label();
    var injurLabel = new Label();
    var natureTextbox = new TextBox();
    var dateTextbox = new TextBox();
    var fatalTextbox = new TextBox();
    var injurTextbox = new TextBox();

    //Validations 

    var dateRegex = new RegularExpressionValidator();

    //*****CURRENT IDEA THAT ISNT WORKING***********************************
    Session["Nature" + (TotalNumberAdded - 1)] = natureTextbox.Text.ToString(); 
    Session["Date" + (TotalNumberAdded - 1)] = dateTextbox.Text.ToString();
    Session["Fatal" + (TotalNumberAdded - 1)] = fatalTextbox.Text.ToString();
    Session["injury" + (controlNumber - 1)] = injurTextbox.Text.ToString();
    //**********************************************************************

    // textbox needs a unique id to maintain state information
    natureTextbox.ID = "NatureTextBox_" + controlNumber;
    dateTextbox.ID = "DateTextbox_" + controlNumber;
    fatalTextbox.ID = "fatalTextbox_" + controlNumber;
    injurTextbox.ID = "injurTextbox_" + controlNumber;

    natureLabel.Text = "Nature Of Accident: ";
    dateLabel.Text = "Date: ";
    fatalLabel.Text = "Fatalities: ";
    injurLabel.Text = "Injuries: ";

    dateRegex.ID = "DateRegex_" + controlNumber;
    dateRegex.Text = "Please enter in format MM/DD/YYY";
    dateRegex.ValidationExpression = @"^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$";
    dateRegex.ControlToValidate = dateTextbox.ID;




    // add the label and textbox to the panel, then add the panel to the form
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table><tr>"));
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='title-text'  >"));
    newPanel.Controls.Add(natureLabel);
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'width='180px'>"));
    newPanel.Controls.Add(natureTextbox);
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text' >"));
    newPanel.Controls.Add(dateLabel);
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
    newPanel.Controls.Add(dateTextbox);
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    newPanel.Controls.Add(dateRegex);
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));

    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td class='title-text'>"));
    newPanel.Controls.Add(fatalLabel);
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
    newPanel.Controls.Add(fatalTextbox);
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
    newPanel.Controls.Add(injurLabel);
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
    newPanel.Controls.Add(injurTextbox);
    newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr></table><br /><hr />"));
    AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(newPanel);


}
protected int TotalNumberAdded
{
    get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] ?? 0); }
    set { ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] = value; }


}




protected void AccidentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TotalNumberAdded++;
    AddControls(TotalNumberAdded);

}
protected void PrevPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Redirect("employment_driversapplication_personalinfo.aspx");

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, bear in mind that the values are only persisted when you click 'add' - so i would suggest another save button or something to persist the values when not adding a new item.

```
public partial class TestRJF2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private IList<TextBox> AddedControls = new List<TextBox>();
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        BuildControls();
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    private void BuildControls()
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < TotalNumberAdded; x++)
        {
            var id = String.Format("NatureTextBox{0}", x);
            //Check if control was already added 
            //only create controls that are new for this postback
            if (AccidentPlaceHolder.FindControl(id) == null)
            {
                var textBox = new TextBox() {ID = id};
                AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(textBox);
                AddedControls.Add(textBox);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var ctrl in AddedControls)
        {
            var key = ctrl.ID.Replace("TextBox", String.Empty);
            Session[key] = ctrl.Text;
        }

        foreach (string session in Session.Keys)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", session, Session[session]));
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    protected void AccidentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TotalNumberAdded++;
        BuildControls();
    } 
    protected int TotalNumberAdded
    {
        get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] ?? 0); }
        set { ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] = value; }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I plan on doing that on the "Next" button when they go to the next page

Comment: also this code is way over my head...i'm kinda a noob to this and not too sure whats goin on

Comment: You are not a million miles away with your code but you cant save the value to the session when you create the controls as this value has not been populated from `ViewState` yet, so do it in `OnPreRender` - that and also check if the control has already been added as you are re-adding them in `Page_Load` and again in the click event handler.

Comment: so what about the code i already have with the other textbox's and labels...leave them or modify this code?  What part do i put in page_load? Sorry I know a lot of questions but I'm having trouble with this :(

Comment: My code is mearly an example - you need to modify your code to do the things that are missing, which my code will give you an example of how to do. First thing - can you run my code okay and it does it do what you need in terms of persisting the data to sessions.

Comment: yeah i'm starting to realize this...alright thanks man its way more advanced than what i know but i will look into what each part does and break it down! Appreciate it!